# How to show both folders and JSON files in Google Drive Picker?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, google-drive-api

I want to have a Google picker dialog that is showing folders and JSON files.
I'm using `"react-google-drive-picker"` package. It has a method named `openPicker` that we can pass the target mime type to it as an argument and see all files with this type.

```js
openPicker({
  clientId: CLIENT_ID,
  developerKey: API_KEY,
  setIncludeFolders: true,
  setSelectFolderEnabled: true,
  viewMimeTypes: "application/vnd.google-apps.folder and application/json",
});
```

I know the mimeType of folders is `application/vnd.google-apps.folder` and the mimeType of JSON files is `application/json in Google drive API.

But I don't how should I mix these 2 mimeTypes to show both folders and JSONs in my picker.

Comment: [Try with comma](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/reference#:~:text=Set%20the%20list%20of%20selectable%20MIME%20types.%20Use%20commas%20to%20separate%20MIME%20types%20if%20more%20than%20one%20is%20required.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use comma to set multiple MIME types. e.g.

```json
viewMimeTypes: "application/vnd.google-apps.folder,application/json",
```

[docs](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/reference#:%7E:text=Set%20the%20list%20of%20selectable%20MIME%20types.%20Use%20commas%20to%20separate%20MIME%20types%20if%20more%20than%20one%20is%20required.)